# RegEx Match String containing CRLF in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying make a regular expression to match a string that includes the CRLF. This is to verify that the CRLF is present in the given string.

I'm using:

```
Regex.IsMatch(allRead, "^the dog jumped\r\n$", RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

But I'm not having any success.

Comment: I'd recommend you have a look at a tool like http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm (free) to allow you to quickly test different patterns, input and see an explanation of why the pattern is matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the **singleLine** option, and then putting linefeeds in your pattern. Any strike you as maybe a little off with that?

Try **Multiline**.

Are you trying to get the last line in the entire string?

Edit...

With this **input**:

```
gd
fg
dfg
the dog jumped
the cat jumped
the dog jumped
the dog jumped
```

With multiline on, try this regex...

```
^the dog jumped$
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: I was a little confused here. I've tried both Multiline and Singleline regex options. Neither appear to work properly.

Comment: I use SingleLine to match multiple lines.  As per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx, the single line option makes `.` match any character including newline.  So `hello.*world` *won't* match `"hello  \n  world"` (a multiline text block) *unless* the SingleLine option is specified!  Must be the most confusingly named option ever.

Answer (score 3):

Try either:

```
Regex.IsMatch(allRead, "the dog jumped\\r\\n")
Regex.IsMatch(allRead, @"the dog jumped\r\n")
```

Unless your expecting `allread` to contain only "then dog jumped\r\n"

i.e you don't need the `^` - unless you want to only match if "the dog" is at the start of the string (or start of the line if you use `RegexOptions.Multiline`)

you also probably don't want the `$` unless you want to ensure that the new line is the end of the string (or the next line is blank if you use `RegexOptions.Multiline`)

Answer (score 2):

try it as below.

```
Regex.IsMatch(allRead, "^the dog jumped\r\n$", RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

this may help you.